# How can I sum a list of string objects in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, sum

I want to make a function that takes a list which contains some words and prints only the first letter of each word in order to make one new word. 
So my function is right here:

```
def word(x):
    li = []
    for w in x:
        li.append(w[0])
    return sum(li)
```

But unfortunately, it gives me the following error: 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Can you please explain me why is this happening ?

Comment: `sum` is for adding up numbers. If you want to join together a list of strings into one string, use `''.join(mylist)`.

Comment: The default starting value for `sum` is `0`, hence it is trying to add the first character to `0`. You should use `str.join`.

Comment: Did you mean concatenation?

Comment: I didn't know that use of .join method. Thank you for the fast responding !

Answer (score 2):

assuming words are separated by space,

```
S="this is my sentense"

"".join(map(lambda x: x[0], S.split(" ")))
```

returns

```
'tims'
```

explanation :

- split in words using space
- for each word ("map" function), take first character (x[0])
- then join the result using void

Comment: or simply `"".join([x[0] for x in S.split(" ")])`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis No need for `[]`, `"".join(x[0] for x in S.split())` suffices here.

Comment: @RoadRunner There are rumors that building the list is actually faster. I'll try to find a link for you.

Comment: Hmm please do, I'm curious about that.

Comment: @RoadRunner Actually, `''join` is special, and [passing lists to it are actually faster than passing generators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/4909087).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Wow, I didn't know that. I guess I learnt something new today.